# Identification of an insect found near Shirdi, Maharashtra

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

[image: Insect found inhouse near Shirdi]

I found the insect nside house near Shirdi, Maharashtra. I have captured the image

Comment: Please add some description about it, like its size.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

It's a household centipede whose scientific name is *Scutigera coleoptrata*.
It's venom doesn't do much harm to humans.

Sources:
[Picture 1](http://pre10.deviantart.net/45bc/th/pre/i/2009/299/0/0/house_centipede__by_megamimao.jpg) and   [Picture 2](http://www.hgtv.com/design/outdoor-design/landscaping-and-hardscaping/house-centipede)

Comment: I agree completely with the genus, but I don't know enough to be able to say if the species ID is correct. How do you know it's _coleoptrata_ rather than another _Scutigera_ species?